# Is a [spoiler] tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

We have a recently created [spoiler](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag, which is currently attached to two questions. Both of those questions are also tagged with [risk-legacy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risk-legacy), but if we left this tag alone, it's likely it would be tagged to questions for other board games as well.

It seems to me that this tag is wholly unnecessary since questions themselves can block out content in spoilers:

> Spoilers are blocked out like this.

One of those questions already uses this spoiler block anyway.

Since we already have ways to denote a spoiler, should we just get rid of the tag altogether?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we do not need a [spoiler](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag. It describes the question itself, not the topic of the question. Tags like this are known as *meta tags*, and are [explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I have removed it from those two questions.

Comment: @Rainbolt Thanks, I knew there was an official statement about it but I forgot to check the blog.